# Multisite site home not loading

Tags: multi-site-manager, htaccess

I'm missing something really simple... I have an MSM site that is `subdomain.domain.com`. These really simple .htaccess rules work ... kind of.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)/index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|swf|pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The template routes work fine. For example, I have set a home template group at `pages` with `index` and `non-index` named templates. If you visit `subdomain.domain.com/pages/index`, it works just fine. Same with `subdomain.domain.com/pages/non-index`.

Now, I've set the `pages` template group to be the site home group, remember:

```
Make the index template in this group your site's home page? **Checked !!**
```

But when I visit `subdomain.domain.com`, I get:

```
Error

The page you requested was not found.
```

Soooo... these routes all work:

```
https://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/ ->
    loads pages/index

https://subdomain.domain.com/pages ->
    loads pages/index

https://subdomain.domain.com/pages/non-index ->
    loads pages/non-index

https://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/pages ->
    loads pages/index

https://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/pages/non-index ->
    loads pages/non-index
```

But yet the `pages/index` doesn't render on the homepage. I get the EE `page not found` error.

I've made sure my `site_url` is set to `https://subdomain.domain.com`, and that the name of my site index is blank.

I've tried a few variations on the last `RewriteRule` line (adding the question mark), but those either render the same or result in the issue where **only** the homepage renders for URLS (so `https://subdomain.domain.com` DOES load `pages/index`, but so does `https://subdomain.domain.com/pages/non-index`).

Like I said, I've tried a bunch of variations of rules to remove index.php and a variation of rules to route everything to index.php after removing it. Any one notice anything stupid I'm missing?

**Edit** 
Like I mentioned, modifying the last rewrite to something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# or
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]

# or (subdomain.domain.com is a folder in the web root)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomain.domain.com/index.php?/$1 [L]

# or
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomain.domain.com/index.php?$1 [L]

# or any of those with the QSA flag
```

results in the issue where **only** the site index template renders.

**Edit** Last edit:

Here's how I load my subdomain folder from my main web root so this subdomain loads the MSM subdomain site. This is at the top of my web root `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !subdomain.domain.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomain.domain.com/$1 [L]
```

That has worked fine in other sites I've worked on and looked at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, so turning off Strict URLs fixed this issue. If anyone else has this issue and doesn't think to tick that off, try it.

If anyone reads through this and feels like commenting, please let me know if turning off Strict URLs has resulted in any issues, especially security ones, in your experience.